# How to disable template if a template parameter is not provided?

Tags: c++

If I have:

```
template< typename T >
foo( T bar )
{
  // do stuff.
}
```

How can I disable the template from being used if someone writes

```
int bar;
foo(bar)?
```

Let me explain a bit further:

```
template< typename T, typename Y > inline void
destroy( T &t, Y &y )
{
}

template< typename T, typename Y > inline void
destroy( T &t, Y &&y )
{
}

template< typename T > inline void
destroy( T &t, unsigned long int &y )
{
}
```

If I type

```
destroy< unsigned long int >( something, 10 )
```

It calls

```
template< typename T, typename Y > inline void
    destroy( T &t, Y &&y )
```

Comment: What do you mean 'disable'? As in not use the angle-bracket syntax? That's type-deduction and works fine. The compiler will interpet `foo<int>( 100 )` the same as `foo( 100 )`.

Comment: You want to force people to explicitly say foo<myType>(bar) instead of having it implied by the parameter?

Comment: @WilliamCustode It should be pointed out that this is only true for *functions*, if foo is a constructor for a `template <typename T> class foo` then your SOL.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams, Unless you create a `make_foo` function.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but you can disable specific instanciations using static_asserts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The template parameter can be deduced from the function parameters, so it need not be explicitly specified.

You can avoid that by making deduction fail:

```
template<typename T>
struct wrap { typedef T type; };

template<typename T>
void foo(typename wrap<T>::type bar);

void test()
{
        foo(3);         // fails
        foo<int>(3);    // works
}
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of this? Smart, but pretty pointless imo (but that's on the OP).

Comment: Note: this is playing on *non-deducible contexts* for those interested in digging in :)

Comment: I will mark this as the wright answer. Though, it is not really what I wanted to see. I hate that it decides to use a template which expects 2 template arguments when only 1 is provided and a template which expects 1 template argument is free to be chosen but is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop automatic template deduction from taking place, any more than you can stop the rain.

What you can do is provide specializations for the types you *do* want the template instantiated for, and not provide an implementation for the non-specialized version.

```
template< typename T >
foo( T bar );

template<> foo <int> (int bar)
{
  // do stuff.
}
```

This will provide a `foo` specialization *only* for `int` types, or types that are convertible to `int`.